# customising a site page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm in the process of building a home page. The page has several sections and iv'e edited the page in SPD to add tables and webparts, mostly JSOM code.
The problem is that there is a lot of code on this page and its not reuseable.
Are there any recommended ways i.e. using webparts instead ? or Iframes to make it a bit more readable and modular?
Thanks

Comment: it depenends on what you are trying to achieve.. I would definitely recommend you to use webparts instead